# c# how to save dictionary to a text file

Tags: c#, file, dictionary

I am trying to save dictionary in txt file and I am looking for simple examples.Can you help me,please? I am trying this but it does not work for me.Thanks.

```
Dictionary<string, int> set_names = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        //fill dictionary 
        //then do:
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in set_names)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0};{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
        }

        string filePath = @"C:\myfile.txt";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
```

Comment: Check out [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @juharr: That requires the dictionary to be stored entirely in RAM first.  Not an issue for small amounts of data, but not a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: @EricJ. It's already stored in RAM in the example with the `StringBuilder`.  Also with a little Linq you can use `File.WriteAllLines` instead without needed to clog up the RAM.

Comment: @juharr: Yes, and that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You are writing the contents of your dictionary into `sb` but never using it.  There is no need to first create an in-memory copy of your dictionary (the StringBuilder).  Instead, just write it out as you enumerate the dictionary.

```
string filePath = @"C:\myfile.txt";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in set_names)
    {
        tw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx) and some Linq

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    path, 
    dictionary.Select(kvp => string.Format("{0};{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
```

Note that this will write to the file as it loops through the dictionary thus not using any additional memory.

Comment: Note `If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.`  This is the same behavior though that the OP gets with the current `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.  Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(YOUFILEPATHSTRING);
try
{
 foreach(KeyValuePair kvp in set_names)
 {
   sw.WriteLine(kvp.Key +";"+kvp.Value;
 }

 sw.Close();
}

catch (IOException ex)
{
 sw.Close();
}
```

This code create a stream pointed to the file you are writing to, loops over the Key value pairs and write them one by one to the file. The stream should be closed in the event of successful completion or if an IO exception is caught, otherwise the file may still opened by the process.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, you will never close the stream, leaving the file locked.

Comment: Well, the file handle would eventually be released, even in case of an exception being thrown. At which time that would happen depends on when the GC would run or when the program would exit (whatever comes first). This could be within 5 seconds, but also could be in 5 months...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: You are right. I don't mean to write production ready code in here but you are absolutely right.